# javascript if condition issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a variable CampaignType and it's value is 0.But in the alert(inside double star) it changes to 1.why so?
here is my javascript code snippet

```
      if (CampaignType != 2) 
      {
       if (CampaignType = '1') 
        {
            **alert(CampaignType);**
            var CampaignAmount = (SelValue * CampaignPrice) / 100;
            SelValue = SelValue - (CampaignAmount);

        }
        else if (CampaignType = '0')
        {
            SelValue = SelValue - CampaignPrice;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Issue is with your comparison blcok...`if (CampaignType = '1')` this `=`assign value in JS and `==` is used for comparison...Check this out on operators http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: sorry guys...its my mistake.please dont downvote me..:(

Comment: @MayankPathak, please refrain from linking to w3schools (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve. (If you use Google Search, and you have a Google account, you can [easily block results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) from w3schools)

Comment: @freefaller man, seeing a guy first time talking against w3schools...well i checked your above posted link but i doesn't makes sense for me..because i don't care about that what that site is saying about w3schools..but I've found it useful for me many a times thus i'll recommend others too..

Comment: @Mayank - if you want to promote a site that is full of problems, inconsistancies and faults - and widely disliked on Stackoverflow - then that is your choice and I will not stop you... however, I will make my position clear on the matter

Comment: @freefaller well, i ain't promoting it anyhow..i'm not getting any revenue from that site :P ... i just said basics of w3schools helped me sometimes that's it that's why i found it useful only for "ME". that's it...

Comment: @freefaller dude i know their javascript education sucks, http://www.codecademy.com/ is much better, but w3schools got valid xhtml and css2 education.

Answer (score 5):

`=` is the assignment operator.

`==` is the comparison operator.

`===` is the identity operator.

[Take a look on how to compare in JavaScript!](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm)

Your code should be:

```
if (CampaignType != 2) 
  {
   if (CampaignType == 1) 
    {
        alert(CampaignType);
        var CampaignAmount = (SelValue * CampaignPrice) / 100;
        SelValue = SelValue - (CampaignAmount);

    }
    else if (CampaignType == 0')
    {
        SelValue = SelValue - CampaignPrice;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the value 1 to `CampaingType`:

```
CampaignType = '1'
```

If you want to compare:

```
CampaignType == '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning it, do:

```
if (CampaignType == '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's beacuse you are not evaluating but setting a value

use

```
if (CampaignType === '1') //if you also want to verify they are the same type

if (CampaignType == '1') //if you do not want to verify if they are the same type
```